# Fixed footer auto expanding outside?

Tags: html, css, fixed, parallax, sticky-footer

I want to use this parallax effect http://jsfiddle.net/KsdeX/1/light/
but the only problem is when using min-height and not a fixed height the footer expands inside depending on the footer content .

Below is the example with the auto sizing
http://jsfiddle.net/KsdeX/62/

So is there any way to push or to make the fixed footer to auto expand outside and not below the body content?

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper-parallax">
    <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="content">
        <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 body {
    margin: 0;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100px;
    background: cyan;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
    min-height: 500px;
}
wrapper-parallax {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0;
    background: green;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand how it's working? `position: fixed`, with `bottom: 0` will take the element entirely out of the document flow and attach it to the bottom of the screen no matter what. The only reason you're able to see the header or footer at all is because of your margins on .`wrapper-parallax`, which equate to the exact heights of those elements. Changing the height of either without anticipating this and changing the margin of the wrapper will result in the excess height being obscured. Because those elements are outside of the document flow, they can't affect other elements dynamically.

Comment: ^ This is a comment rather than an answer, because I don't have a solution for you, but I'd suggest that you might be able to do some script calculations to modify the heights dynamically. Rebuilding/rethinking the structure of it might be a better option (to avoid scripting), though nothing obvious is jumping out at me.

Comment: this can be useful for you: [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique--net-27641)

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I understand how it works and i know that changing the height of the footer i must change the margin of the content also..but is there any possible way to have both auto adjust ?

Comment: Posted an answer that utilises jQuery below. Hopefully it's what you're looking for!

Comment: @brobken - thanks but i'm not looking for a parallax tutorial as i already have this one.What i want is to make the footer from my example to auto increase height depending on the footer content but in the same time the margin of the body content to auto increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to calculate the height of your `footer` when the page loads, then assign that value with `.css()` to the `margin-bottom` of `.wrapper-parallax`.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var footerHeight = $('footer').height();
    $('.wrapper-parallax').css('margin-bottom', footerHeight); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/KsdeX/63/